# How to increase quantity in magento based on dates attribute?

Tags: magento

I am building house rental website using magento. I am taking 2 dates from users. one is 'from' and another is 'till'. How can I calculate total number of days and change quantity in cart?

Comment: Please elaborate your question. What do you mean by changing quantity in cart?or what is the relation between days and quantity and in which page you want this funtionality, in product page?

Answer (score 0):

```
$from = new DateTime('2015-02-20');
$to = new DateTime('2015-02-26');
$interval = $from->diff($to);
$numberOfDays = (int) $interval->format('%R%a');
```

Comment: Please [edit] in an explanation of why/how this code answers the question? Code-only answers are discouraged, because they are not as easy to learn from as code with an explanation. Without an explanation it takes considerably more time and effort to understand what was being done, the changes made to the code, if the code answers the question, etc.  The explanation is important both for people attempting to learn from the answer and those evaluating the answer to see if it is valid, or worth up voting.

Comment: While this code block may answer the question, it would be a better answer if you could provide some explanation for why it does so.